# "Пропажа" памяти в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Вопрос немного не по теме, но может кто знает. Возникла  проблема. На Ubuntu 10.04 стала пропадать память. Удаляю кучу файлов, чтобы хоть немного пространства получить, но памяти не увеличивается. Доступно 0 байт. Есть предположение что файловый менеджер некорректно считает память. А может какое приложение оттяпало столько. В общем, как можно  это проследить или исправить? Спасибо

Comment: @carapuz, сразу после reboot картина та же самая?

Comment: Да, все оставалось по-прежнему. Удалил виртуальную винду, появилось 10 гб места. А когда удалял фильмы по 1,5 гб, реакции не было. В чем может быть дело, не знаю

Comment: Так может удаленные файлы попали в корзину? Может, корзину проверить и почистить?

Comment: Файлы на разных разделах? Удалять файла - шифт+делит. Корзина в бубунте - гугл/убунтариум скажет - я не знаю.

выхлоп df в студию. 

Comment: Дело точно не в корзине, файлы удаляю по Shift+Delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотреть какие папки и файлы занимают много места можно программами типа [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) или [gdmap](http://gdmap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: думаю, все дело в корзине.

Answer (score 4):

Видимо какие то апдейты не могут нормально сесть и он генерирует новые и новые папки. Посмотрите в разделе Home-User. Нажмите CTRl+H (кажется так: показать скрытые папки). Взвесте каждую папку и посмотрите, то что много весит снесте. Данная проблема была и у меня под Debian. Тогда я устанавливал какой то сервер кажется был LAMP сервер точно не помню. Но проблему решил только через удаление в ручную.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то в таком стиле было у меня в linux mint (который основан на ubuntu). Решил я эту проблему просто - в файловом менеджере нашёл вкладку 'корзина' и отчистил всё, что там было